# Symfony2: Where do I place my univeral helper class

Tags: symfony

I'm new to `Symfony2` and would like to know the proper place to put my universal helper class. The helper class contains things like `removeCurseWords`, `uplodFile`, `resizeImage`, `watermarkImage`, `convertDateToServerTime`, `doStuffHere` and other things used by many but belong to none. I want this class to be accessible to all the bundles in my app so where do I place it to make it available to all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 where to place custom helper classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759096/symfony2-where-to-place-custom-helper-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group those methods and put them in services (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). That way you can use them cross-bundle via the service container. You could have one service for all image operations and one for the rest which doesn't fit elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your php Library i suggest you to write a bundle that wrap it for symfony2 usage for, as example, expose the functionality as services container, manage the initialization, implement for type and so on for enable your library in yhe symfony2 way, then you can share via composer in other projects.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy) for further details.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I always create a folder called "Utils" at the same level as Controllers, Repositories, etc Found several people doing it that way too.